# shor t way to select from multiple tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am displaying every article from all the tablesof my DB that a certain user has posted on my website. I have 16 tables in my DB and this is my code for two of them and it does the job. But I just don't see myself doing 16 UNIONS in that code, it's too long. Is there any short way to do it? can someone help?

thank you !

```
$sql = "SELECT title, price, pays, date, urlimage FROM ads WHERE user= '$login_session' 
  UNION SELECT title, price, pays, date, urlimage FROM telephones WHERE user= '$login_session'";
```

Comment: create a view and fetch data from it . performance point it will  same but you will get easy access

Comment: That code you've shared to me is an indication that you probably could have designed your DB differently, i.e. `article` table with a `type` column instead of many tables that essentially hold the same information.

Comment: thanx i'll try both answers